# How to remove all the extra horizontal scroll space in BBEdit

Tags: bbedit

In BBEdit, it shows so much extra space on the right side of my document, forcing the bottom scroll bar to appear. This is really annoying for me, since whenever I scroll up or down, I inevitably also scroll a little horizontally, obscuring the code on the left even though there's nothing on the right to see!

Is there any way I can make the default page size smaller and get rid of this scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out this was really easy.

You go up to View > Text Display. Check "Soft Wrap Text" and at "Window width". Then the horizontal scrollbar will disappear and the text will only wrap when there's no space left in the window. Also, to remove the gray "page guide", uncheck "Show page guide".

To make the change for all documents (will only apply to new ones though), go to Preferences > Editor Defaults and make the same changes there.